# Как задать размер отдельным элементам GridLayout?

Tags: python, kivy

Хочу задать разные height элементам списка, но Grid игнорирует размеры элементов и ставит одинаковую для всех height 120, даже прописанный `row_force_default=False` не помогает.

Вот как это происходит.

Заполняю Grid циклом из разных элементов Button, ToggleButton, Image и Label.
Код Grid:

```
self.layout = GridLayout(cols=1,rows=0, padding=10, spacing=0, 
                        width=Window.width,size_hint=(None, None), 
                        row_force_default=False, row_default_height=120)
```

Потом просто запихиваю Grid в ScrollView для прокрутки:

```
root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height),
                  pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}, do_scroll_x=False)
```

Comment: Сталкивался с этим вопросом, посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50824029/kivy-how-to-change-size-of-elements-inside-grid-layout

Comment: К сожалению kv код мало что мне дал, я всё чисто на python пишу

Answer (score 0):

В .py можно так:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        grid = GridLayout(cols=3)
        grid.add_widget(Button(text='first'))
        grid.add_widget(Button(text='second'))
        anchor = AnchorLayout()
        anchor.add_widget(Button(size_hint_x=None, height=100, text='third'))
        grid.add_widget(anchor)
        return grid

MyApp().run()
```